How to simulate the size of a 3D printer nozzle onto a design?
I am trying to convert a black and white drawing into a 3D printable design.
While the vector graphics are able to create infinitely sharp angles, a 3D printer has an unshrinkable nozzle size that won't allow for that. Every pointy end and narrow lines are therefore affected.
And this is the situation I if want to only print the black part. If I also want to print the white background on the same layer, the issue is doubled:
Up until now, my 3D Slicer seems to avoid the problematic zones and simply let them empty.
Is there a way to tell Photoshop, 3D slicers or any other software to automatically implement the size of the 3D printer nozzle and create rounded points and thicker lines?
If so, is there a way to be able to choose between one and several filaments?

Use illustrator it has the toolset you want. But thei isnt really a graphic design question

Adobe Illustrator has rounded corner widgets - try using that. Photoshop only has very basic vector capabilities because it's a raster image editor. It's essentially the wrong kind of software.

Though seriously, wouldnt it make sense to just export the Gcode as svg and then just stroke that
